# Make Visual Studio warn for unsigned comparisons

Tags: c, visual-studio

This code, when compiled with Visual Studio 2010

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int numbers[] = { 23, 24, 25, 25, 28, 20, 20 };

int main(void) {
    int d = -1, x=0;
    size_t count = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);

    if (d <= (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]))-2)
        x = numbers[d+1];

    if (d <= count-2)
        x = numbers[d+1];
}
```

gives me a signed/unsigned mismatch warning on `if (d <= count-2)` but not on `if (d <= (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]))-2)`. Why is this? I have enabled *all* warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug that the Visual C++ compiler does not emit warning C4018 in this case.  See the Microsoft Connect bug report, ["warning C4018 (signed/unsigned mismatch) for sizeof operator."](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/569898/warning-c4018-signed-unsigned-mismatch-for-sizeof-operator)

The issue appears to be only indirectly related to usage of `sizeof`.  The compiler also fails to emit the warning in other cases where a constant value of unsigned type is involved in the comparison.  For example, if you add `const`-qualification to `count`, C4018 is not emitted even for your second comparison.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it treats `2` as an int so promotes 
`(sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]))-2)` to an int because of the brackets and so the comaprison is `int < int`

Comment: removing -2 also does not flag off the statement as having sign mismatch

Comment: That would be backwards.  When the operands have mixed signedness and the unsigned type has equal or higher rank than the signed type and both types have equal or higher rank than `int`, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned type.  So, here, where the operands are of types `int` and `size_t`, the `int` operand (`d`) is converted to `size_t` (yielding a very large positive number) and the comparison is performed on the two `size_t` values.

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is defined as unsigned so you get a signed unsigned conflict.

Please note, as `sizeof` is evaluated during compile time, and is being replaced by a constant value, it does not complain about sign mismatch, but in the other expression, you explicitly convert the value to a size_t variable which can possibly overflow when you try to compare with a signed number.

Comment: A `sizeof` expression is also of type `size_t`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: sizeof return a compile time constant so the comparison happens to compare with a constant not with an unsigned variable.

Comment: The value is still of type `size_t`.  Whether an expression is evaluated at compile-time or at run-time does not affect the types involved in the expression.  There is nothing in the program that cannot be computed at compile-time.